# Design Questions regarding Building CordApps Application

Tags: corda

I'm new to corda and getting my head around it. So what I understand is only important data should go to the block chain. example in an exchange of physical contract that's to be shared. I should only create the State of the contract. because that's important and should be immutable.

```
// From the example on CORDA site
flowProgressHandle<SignedTransaction> flowHandle = rpcOps
                    .startTrackedFlowDynamic(TestFlow.Initiator.class, iouValue, otherParty);
 //so this is  how flow would begin I'll pass the value of the otherParty and and I'll get my node information in the TestFlow.Initiator class something like this
IOUState iouState = new IOUState(iouValue, getServiceHub().getMyInfo().getLegalIdentities().get(0), otherParty);
```

now **getServiceHub().getMyInfo().getLegalIdentities().get(0)** -> this gives me my own node as a party as IOUstate constructor takes in lender and owner.

how can I get more information about the owner? Like what is his occupation or hobbies where can I store that to get it?. In the CORDA example I see they provided name in here it doesn't make sense to put hobbies and occupation in here. how to tackle this. I want send and receive Singed

```
node {
        name "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
        advertisedServices = []
        p2pPort 10005
        rpcPort 10006
        webPort 10007
        cordapps = ["net.corda:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
    }
```

now another question is how to initialize CordaRPCOps rpcOps explicitly ??? because it seems that's required to begin things.

now if I want to get all the contracts which below to partyA do a query on the STATE so that I get the result from H2 DB? Can't I store the parties as well on the block chain with one to many relationship with the STATE of the contract that's being shared? how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

So there's a few questions there... but I'll answer the one that is "How to initialize CordaRPCOps rpcOps explicitly?" - and the answer is that you can't (and you shouldn't) create an instance of this explicitly. You will either get one if you have connected to a running corda node via the RPC interface or you are in a Corda "Flow".

I am guessing you'd like to connect to a node and get an instance that way - here's how I do it in https://github.com/ragmondo/cordaftp/blob/3d1fd9f636d85803206cae18b522b0c4884d2453/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/cordaftp/Sender.kt#L21

```
import net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient
import net.corda.core.messaging.CordaRPCOps
import net.corda.core.utilities.NetworkHostAndPort


fun loginToCordaNode(args: Array<String>): CordaRPCOps {
    val nodeAddress = NetworkHostAndPort.parse(args[0])
    val client = CordaRPCClient(nodeAddress)
    return client.start("user1", "test").proxy
}
```

Obviously change `user1` and `test` appropriately, but as you can see this returns an object of type `CordaRPCOps`

Answer (score 0):

as ^ rich has already answered about to initialize the RPC Ops, I'll answer the other part.

we ended up using `NODE_PROPERTIES` table to store information related to the node. we did this in `corda 3.1` probably there is a better way to do this in the latest version of corda, which I'm not very sure of.

In `NODE_PROPERTIES` table you can store any key-value pair  as long as they don't clash with keys used for internal purposes. we tweaked our jenkins job, it would now execute a sql script on the node ledger and update`NODE_PROPERTIES` with appropriate values that were needed after the bootstrapping was done. you can then easily read the table using `jdbc` and do whatever you need even update as required.

another way would be, to create `corda-service` and in it's constructor execute the sql you want to update or create any table with whatever info reasonable to you. have this as a separate cordapp and deploy on any node. you can abstract the sql script out and put it up somewhere in the cloud and download it based on some-key which could be your node name this way each node will use it's own predefined script.